# How to include file php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with including a php file

*PagePrevie.php* :

```
<html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <script src="Style/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/css/Header-Picture.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/css/Footer-with-logo.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body class="container  lg-warning"> 
 <?php
        include 'include/LogoUMBB.php';
        include 'include/Header.php';
        ?>    
<div class="container bg-success  text-primary"  style="width:500px;padding: 20px;">  
 </div>  
<br />  
<?php
        include 'include/Footer.php';
        ?>       
</body>  
</html>
```

The problem is that this file is located in a directory that contains other web page with the same code

And here is the structure of files:

[image]

Comment: maybe need to do some reading about syntax how to include a file

Answer (score 1):

PHP told you your path is incorrect, add "../" so you get correct include path.

```
    include '../include/LogoUMBB.php';
    include '../include/Header.php';
    include '../include/Footer.php';
```

Comment: include '../include/LogoUMBB.php';
    include '../include/Header.php';
    include '../include/Footer.php'; what is this? include is a build in function which means it uses () and he only needs it once so include_once("../includes/header.php");

Comment: But for what ... I have tow file for example 'a.php' and 'b.php' which locate in a repertory rep1 and 'a.php' include a file 'c.php' which locate in another repertoir rep2 by the following code -----include 'rep2 / c.php'---
For which the same code include 'rep2 / c.php' does not work in the file 'b.php' ............ think you

Comment: @Gert: `Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @JEEdz, I think you need to structure your files correctly. If you have to do "./" and "../" in front of include, you're not using it correctly. Usually, all files are run from {root} directory then you include by:
$file = '/include/Header.php';

include __DIR__.$file;
or
include(__DIR__.$file);

DIR is php magic constant (look it up)